# How to merge two separate SQL update statements on the same table as one command?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

```
UPDATE table SET val1 = val1 + 1 where (val1 < $1 AND val1 >= ($1-$3));
update table set (val1,val2) = (val1 - $3, val2 + 1) WHERE val3 = $2 RETURNING %s
```

Unfortunately this is giving an error "cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement". Is there a way to merge these two statements into one?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  In Postgres you can use CTEs:

```
with u1 as (
      update table set val1 = val1 + 1 where (val1 < $1 AND val1 >= ($1-$3))
     ),
     u2 as (
      update table set (val1,val2) = (val1 - $3, val2 + 1) WHERE val3 = $2 RETURNING %s
     )
select *
from u2;
```